# A number divided by 47, the remainder is 1 Same number divided by 48, the remainder is 2 Same number divided by 49, the remainder is 3

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A number divided by $47$, the remainder is $1$.
> Same number divided by $48$, the remainder is $2$.
> Same number divided by $49$, the remainder is $3$.
> Calculate the number:

I have this setup but do not know what to do next.

Let $x$ be the number, then

$x = 47r + 1$ for some natural number $r$.

$x = 48s + 2$ for some natural number $s$.

$x = 49t + 3$ for some natural number $t$.

How can I use this information to find $x$?

Comment: Look up algorithms for Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: Note that $-46$ works. How can you use that to get other solutions?

Comment: There are infinitely many such numbers, since for any solution $n$, you can add any multiple $47 \cdot 48 \cdot 49$ to get another solution.

Comment: thanks a lot all!!

Answer (score 0):

For $ r,s,t \in \Bbb Z, \; x=47r+1,\;x= 48s+2,\;x=49t+3$

$\iff x+46=47(r+1), \; x+46=48(s+1), \;x+46=49(t+1)$

That means, the required number can be any real number $x$ which satisfy the above three equations, i.e., $x+46$ just needs to be a multiple of $47, 48$ and $49$, which is equivalent to saying that $x+46$ should be a multiple of $47.48.49$.

This implies $x+46=47.48.49k$ for some $k \in \Bbb Z$.

$\therefore x=47.48.49k-46$

Thus $x$ can any element of the set $\{47.48.49k-46 \;| \;k \in \Bbb Z\}$

Comment: thank you ever so much!!. that was a lot of help!!!!.

Comment: You are welcome @Eddy